# Is the mathematical physics tag appropriate for this post?

Tags: discussion, tags

I am not sure if the mathematical physics tag would be appropriate for this post:

[Can You Obtain New Physics from the use of Fractional Derivatives?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/89922/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I) *Yes,* it seems the [mathematical-physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mathematical-physics) tag applies to fractional derivatives, in particular since [fractional calculus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_calculus) is a relatively advanced mathematical discipline, which is rarely covered in a standard university curriculum.

II) More generally, for the most common tags [insert-tagname-here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/insert-tagname-here), there is:

1. a short pop-up wiki tag excerpt available by hovering the mouse over the tag in the main Phys.SE site, or
2. a longer wiki tag description at https://physics.stackexchange.com/tags/insert-tagname-here/info,

where one can learn more about the [insert-tagname-here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/insert-tagname-here) tag. If not, then users are encouraged to create a wiki tag description (or improve an existing wiki tag description).